# How do people solve NFT cross-chain when developing on your own rollup?

Tags: nft, rollups

This is a question about developing a game using its own side-chain. In this case, the NFTs would be minted on the side chain. Now the players can trade NFTs with each other but some of them might want to move their NFTs back to the main chain. This seems to be a pretty iffy issue as NFT cross-chain is not mature (IMO.) Wonder how do people usually solve this problem?